# Update Parity Node Installation

Tags: parity, nodes, ubuntu

I have 3 nodes, all in Ubuntu 16.04 that I have to upgrade.

To install the node, I downloaded the latest stable version from https://www.parity.io/

and then did:

```
wget wget [LINK_FROM_PARITY]
sudo dpkg -i [FILE_DOWNLOADED_FROM_PARITY]
```

to install it.

What's the best way to upgrade my nodes making sure I don't lose the content of the chain, the enode, the chain config and the peer list?

Does dpkg have an upgrade function or something like that?

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to use dpkg over apt as it's much more lower level. Another reason is apt will look for the newest version, ignoring older local versions as well.

Comment: @Meshugah The tutorial I followed used it instead of apt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes it does**, Another `sudo dpkg -i [FILENAME]` should do it as stated [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php)